# Interpolate pandas dataframe where a pre-specified condition does not exist

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large dataset that I group by to get some summary information. One of the columns refers to a variable that I know should contain a set of values for each condition, regardless of whether it was observed or not. The problem is that some observations do not contain all of the values within the known range, meaning they were not obtained. I need ALL possible instances of the `level` variable to exist. Running the `df.groupby()` means that some combinations do not exist, but I need these for a subsequent step. So I specifically want to interpolate where a condition is missing instances of this variable, and add zeros into another column. Example:

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'condition':['a','a','a','b','b','c','c','c'],
                     'level':[1,2,3,1,2,1,2,3],
                     'value':[6,0,11,4,10,9,14,9]})

    condition   level   value
0   a   1   6
1   a   2   12
2   a   3   11
3   b   1   4
4   b   2   10
5   c   1   9
6   c   2   14
7   c   3   9
```

The levels are `[1,2,3]`, but as you can see, where condition is equal to `'b'`, `level` 3 (for example) is missing. I want to simply go through the entire dataframe and find rows like this, filling in the codition and level, and setting value to be `0` in those cases so that the end result would be like this:

```
    condition   level   value
0   a   1   6
1   a   2   12
2   a   3   11
3   b   1   4
4   b   2   10
5   b   3   0
6   c   1   9
7   c   2   14
8   c   3   9
```

The only way I can think of doing this is by looping through, grabbing the observed levels, checking if they are contained in the full set of levels, and if they are not all there, append a row to pandas with the required information. I could then sort it at the end. But I think this would be highly inefficient due to looping over the dataframe. Any better ideas?

footnote: there is more than one `value` column in the real dataset, but they should all be set to zero in the cases where they are absent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can unstack and fill in the values with 0 and stack back:

```
test.set_index(['condition','level']).unstack(fill_value=0).stack().reset_index()
```

Or similar with pivot_table

```
test.pivot_table(index='condition',columns='level',fill_value=0).stack().reset_index()
```

---

```
  condition  level  value
0         a      1      6
1         a      2      0
2         a      3     11
3         b      1      4
4         b      2     10
5         b      3      0
6         c      1      9
7         c      2     14
8         c      3      9
```

Comment: Thanks, this did the job perfectly for what I need. It seems that this "infers" the full range that `level` can take on based on what exists in the entire column across all `condition`. Is it possible to pre-specify this somehow to ensure that `level` takes on all possible values, regardless of whether they exist in the current data?

Comment: @fffrost IIUC , after unstack , you can `reindex` which also suppoerts a fill_value to specify a list of level and then stack , `df....unstack().reindex(your_list,fill_value=0).stack()` something like this

Comment: also you need `axis=1` in reindex, i missed it in my prev comment code

Answer (score 3):

You can `pivot` the `stack`

```
df=test.pivot(*test.columns).fillna(0).stack().reset_index()
```